# KnockoutJS viewModel binding on multiple pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am working on a ASP MVC web app. On the main page I create a knockout model, dynamically change a few of its properties and then I want to get to another page, and somehow pass that exact viewModel. I'm having problems because when the second page loads, a new viewModel is initialised, therefore, the properties I want are lost.

```
var viewModel = new gameViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This is how I initialize my model. Any ideas? 
I am not sure what code you need here in order to help me so please ask for the needed info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have three options:

- **Store state in the browser**, e.g. using cookies or localStorage;
- **Post state to the server on navigation**, e.g. using form data or query strings, and have the new page re-render that data for your JS to use;
- **Use a state mechanism server side**, e.g. SessionState, and reload it each page load.

That is the direct answer to your somewhat broad questions. For more specific answers, I suggest you try something first, then get back with more specific questions.

PS. LocalStorage is the easiest way to get started, though whether it's suitable depends on browser requirements, security, whether you need to save the state server side too, and other context.